Is color confinement a strict theoretical rule, or is it rather an assumption?
My question is actually quite simple, so I avoid going into technicalities.
The theory of color confinement states that there can’t be individual color charges, and all particles that manifest individually are color neutral. The usual explanation I know is that separating color charges causes a potential well so deep the invested energy causes new particles to appear, with color charges neutralizing the system.
I’m interested if this is a strict, theoretical ban, or rather an assumption, explaining why we can’t observe color charged particles. Is there something in the current mathematical theory of strong interaction that mathematically rules out the existence of an isolated color charge, without exceptions, or is it technically allowed? Does the model, theoretically, allow some room for color charged particles (regardless if other models do not predict the existence of those), and/or exotic situations (such as some specific quark soup arrangement), in which isolated color charges can manifest?
For the purpose of this question, let’s define an “isolated color charge” as any occurrence in which the excepted value of an “integrated color charge” in a region with a sufficiently large characteristic radius (for example 10 times the RMS diameter of a proton, about $10^{-14} m$) is non-neutral. This can be an empty space containing one or few isolated particles, a region in some exotic particle soup, or anything else.

Proving mathematically rigorously the confinement ( that is, the area law coming from the expectation value of a Wilson loop) is a millennium prize problem in four dimensions. However, in 2+1 equations, this is well understood, as per Karabali, Kim, and Nair.

@JeanbaptisteRoux So it is unknown in 3+1D, but the confinement in the analogous theory in 2+1D is theoretically strict? Fascinating!

See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/118825/50583

We have hand-wavy arguments, as in the book of Srednicki (see eq 82.36). But sticky speaking, I should have said "a corollary" of a millennium prize problem (which focuses on the existence and mass gap)
